# Why DIVs and Images are not resizing, but being cutted?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so here we go:
http://judao.com.br/direto-do-epicentro-de-terremoto-a-falha-de-san-andreas/

The content images are huge, 100% width, with a caption. BUT on a 1080p resolution. Anything below that cuts the images, the caption AND the video.

The divs are inside another one, that says max-width: 960px. Here's what I did to make it huge.

```
#tamanhao {
display: inline-block;  
left: -50%; 
outline: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative; 
text-align: center;
height: auto !important;
width: 200%;
}

#tamanhao img { 
max-width: 100% !important; 
padding-top: 32px !important;
height: auto !important;
}

.caption {
float: left;
display: inline;
margin-top: -16px;
font-size: 14px;
color: #888;
padding-left: 32px !important;
max-width: 470px;
font-style: italic;
font-family: exo;
text-align: left  !important;
line-height: 14px !important;
}

#videozao {
display: block;  
left: -50%; 
outline: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative; 
text-align: center;
width: 200%;
max-height: 744px !important;

}

#videozao iframe {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
width: 1280px !important;
height: 720px !important;
position: relative;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it right?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but if I got you right, remove `background-color: #fff !important;` from `h1.Titulo_SINGLE a` of `@media only screen and (max-width: 646px)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using static widths for your content, meaning you're using `px` instead of `percentage`. Percentage will make your content to be responsive in smaller screens fiting the screen while resizing the window, while for example `500px` will always maintain that same value, unless you use media queries. **[Here's a example](http://jsfiddle.net/4t7bnjnr/)**, Resize the window where the images are on this link to see it work.

Code Explanation

```
<div class="responsiveWidth">
    ...Conteúdo Responsivo...
    <img src="http://i1.wp.com/www.24x7photography.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/random2.jpg?w=720" width="500">
</div>

<div class="staticWidth">
    ...Conteúdo Estático...
    <img src="http://i1.wp.com/www.24x7photography.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/random2.jpg?w=720" width="500">
</div>
```

This 2 div's look exaclty the same, but here's where the magic happens
CSS

```
.staticWidth {
    width:500px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.responsiveWidth {
    width:100%; /* This says the div to stay always 100% of it's parent, in this case it's `body` because we don't have any div container */
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.responsiveWidth img{
    width:100%; /* This will make the width of the image 100% as well, the height it's automattic because we didn't set one nor on HTML or CSS */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, guys, I solved it. I never heard about the VW thing... And when I did, it worked. Here's the final solution. :)

```
#tamanhao {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -50vw;
    width: 100vw;
}

#tamanhao img { 
    max-width: 100vw !important; 
    padding-top: 32px !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

#videozao {
position: relative;
left: 50%;
max-height: 720px !important;
margin: 0px 0 0 -50vw;
width: 100vw;
}

#videozao .fve-video-wrapper {
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 1280px !important;
max-height: 720px !important;
}

#videozao iframe {
max-width: 1280px !important;
max-height: 720px !important;
}
```

Thank you / Obrigado! :))))